# Is the step function continuous/homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Here is a topology question, and $T_{st}$ stands for standard topology:

Consider the function f : [−1, 1] → [0, 1] defined by

$$f(t)=
\begin{cases}
t& \text{0 $\leq$ t $\leq$ 1}\\
-t& \text{-1$\leq$ t $\leq$ 0}
\end{cases}$$
(a) Is f : ([−1, 1],$T_{st}$) → ([0, 1],$T_{st}$), continuous?

(b) Is f : ([−1, 1],$T_{st}$) → ([0, 1],$T_{st}$) a homeomorphism?

(c) Is ([−1, 1],$T_{st}$) homeomorphic to ([0, 1],$T_{st}$)?

---

What I got so far:

(a) just use calculus from [0,1], $lim_{t -> 0+}$ t = 0, and from [-1,0] $lim_{t -> 0-}$ t = 0， since LHS = RHS, it's continuous. And since f(t) always goes to a value in the range [0,1], so f is continuous.

(b)it's bijective, and f is continuous, but I'm not sure how to check the inverse of this function.

(c) I think if (b) is homeomorphism, then c must be. But if (b) is not, then I'm not sure how to find the function that goes from ([−1, 1],$T_{st}$) to ([0, 1],$T_{st}$) maybe f(t) = |t|? which takes the absolute value.

Please point out whether I'm correct on each question, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is not a step function. Note that $f(t) = |t|$. How can $f$ be bijective if $f(-1)=f(1)$?

Comment: Assuming that you meant to use $t$ instead of $x$ above, otherwise I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry for the confusion, just updated the question. And I see what you mean, it's not one to one, right?

Comment: Your definition of $f$ needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(t)=
\begin{cases}
t& \text{0 $\leq$ x $\leq$ 1}\\
-t& \text{-1$\leq$ x $\leq$ 0}
\end{cases}$$

(a) Is $f : ([−1, 1],st) → ([0, 1],st)$, continuous?

Yes, it is continuous.

(b) Is $f : ([−1, 1],st) → ([0, 1],st)$ a homeomorphism?

No, it is not one-to-one so it is not homeomorphism.

(c) Is $([−1, 1],st)$ homeomorphic to $([0, 1],st)$?

Yes, the function $f(x)=(x+1)/2$ is a homeomorphism from $[-1,1]$ to $[0,1]$

Comment: Could you further elaborate the answer, like giving why it's not 1 to 1 for b and how does the function works for homeomorphism? Thank you

Comment: For  b the function is not one-to-one because for example f(-1/2) =f(1/2)=1/2.

Comment: For c the function is a linear function mapping [-1,1] onto [0,1]. It is continuous and one- to -one. Its inverse , g(x)= 2x-1 is also continuous, one-to one and onto from [0,1] to [-1,1].